# Value undefined after append Jquery

Tags: jquery, append

I have some trouble with an appending feature. I use this code:

```
        $('.videoblock .title').each(function(){            
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('body').append('<input type="text" id="'+i+'" value="'+href+'">');
        $('body').append($(this).attr('title'));            
    });
```

This will return 2 input fields with a value: undefined and a correct value.
How can this be?

Regards,

Frank

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your HTML structure or produce a quick demo over at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: A fixed it sorry for the question, used an other part of the html thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the value of the input is undefined then that means that it is getting undefined back for the href.  Are the elements with the class "title"  tags with an href?  I would debug and ensure that $(this) is really what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

It's because it updates the DOM in the wrong way. When you use `append`, it'll redefine body's `innerHTML`, causing the DOM to generate all new elements, making your old elements `undefined`. Use `append(element)` rather than `append(html)`.